# can katalon automation recorder be used to manipulate http post parameters

Tags: http, post, parameters, katalon-studio, katalon-recorder

I am using Katalon Automation Recorder to Automate testing a web service my company is developing.

I have been asked to manipulate the HTTP POST protocol parameters submitted to the server when the Submit button is clicked.

This is because my boss doesn't want the test suite to enter values in their designated text box, but instead, edit the code we can see in the source such that the data sent to the server is what we want and can enter, just without using the text boxes for that said data.

I don't know if it is possible to do this using Katalon Recorder and I need someone to tell be definitively, if I can and what command, target and value I am required to enter to achieve this.

Comment: You can't do this with Katalon Recorder.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not tech support for this. Don't they have their own forum to ask such questions?

Comment: Well Rob, if you must know, Kataon does have their own Forum. But the passed three questions I've asked have been unanswered for reason I am not aware of. I am well aware that StackOverflow is not Katalon's "Tech Support", but in its essence, StackOverflow is a "Q&A site for programming problems. If you don't like my question, you are no help, so avoid posting unhelpful answers to real questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is available in `Katalon Studio` since version 5.4. Please check it here: https://docs.katalon.com/display/KD/Parameterize+a+Web+Service+object

[image]